# Readonly OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I'm using an OpenFileDialog in my Windows Form.
I would like this dialog to be read only.

The only thing I would like is that the user can open/load a file.
I would like to be able to disable all the "right mouse click" events (delete, rename etc.)

Is this possible? If not is there another component I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you would want to do this? Most windows users are familiar with the way the `OpenFileDialog` works, and they might be thrown off by something like that.

Comment: There is no point in disabling something that the user can do anyway, just by starting Explorer.

Comment: I'm using it in a touch screen application. The user has no keyboard or mouse. The application is started by default and the user has no access to anything but my application. The only thing I would like the user to be able to do is open a file.

Comment: It's been a long time, did you manage to find a way? We are also building a launcher app and trying to restrict users from accessing things. I checked the below example but it looks like it only expands the capabilities of FileDialog, while we are trying to limit it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be possible, but it probably won't be pretty. it might be better to write your own version of the `OpenFileDialog` where you can customize them as you want in a nice way.

However, if you want to do this, then you might be able to do all you want by getting hold of the Handle for the dialog after which you should be able to add your own event handlers etc as needed (to make it ignore right clicks etc).

Look at this CodeGuru article for details on getting the Handle: [Customizing OpenFileDialog in .NET](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c12801__2/Customizing-OpenFileDialog-in-NET.htm)

This CodeProject article might also be useful: [Extend OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog the easy way](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I will look into this. I actually thought there would be an easier way.